# Still confused about using XMLHTTPRequest cross domain

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I need to POST data to a server in a different domain.  That server is using SSL and expects the data to be in the form of a JSON string.  I am attempting to do this from javascript.

I create the data and use JSON.stringify() to get it into the correct format.  Then I send it as follows:

```
var url = "https://api.postageapp.com/v.1.0/send_message.json";

http=new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

// create the data in a data structure named post_data
var JSONText = JSON.stringify(post_data);
http.send(JSONText);
```

Doing a packet trace I see my client do a handshake with the server but then twice the server replies with "Encrypted alert" including the last time it sends a packet back.  The browser debugger always shows a 405 - Method Now Allowed error.

What am I missing to get this to work?  When they try it within their domain it runs fine.

Comment: Are you attempting this from a page that is http, not https?

Answer (score 1):

You need server to return a HTTP Header like that:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Live example:
[Making cross domain JavaScript requests using XMLHttpRequest or XDomainRequest](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a cross domain post like that.

Alternative is to use [Server side proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) (read this link for a nice explanation as to why you can't do that) or [iframe approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking it should not be possible (due to security issues) however using a workaround called JSONP you can achieve this with a RESTful web service.

See the link below. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

MS has some code you can download somewhere on the internet with specific bindings the code is called.

- JSONPBehaviour.cs
- JSONPBindingElement.cs
- JSONPBindingExtension.cs
- JSONPEncoderFactory.cs

Comment: please update your information, the link from jasonkelly's website is broken