# create Jira issue via REST api and jquery 405 method not allowed

Tags: jquery, rest, jira, http-status-code-405

When using the following jquery call I receive a http 405 method not allowed error message.
Does anybody know how to solve this? Is it due to the https? I tried it also with type GET and PUT with the same result

```
  function make_base_auth(user, password) {
        var tok = user + ':' + password;
        var hash = btoa(tok);
        return "Basic " + hash;
    }   
function createJiraIssue() {

        var datos = {
            "fields": {
                "project":
              {
                  "key": "HELP"
             },
                "summary": "Test Ticket",
                "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type  names using the REST API",
                "issuetype": {
                    "name": "Bug"
                },
                "assignee": { "name": "sim" }
            }
        };

        var parameters = JSON.stringify(datos);
        var req = $.ajax({
            url: 'https://xxx.jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/',
            type: "POST",
            data: parameters,
            contentType: 'application/jsonp',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(user, password));
            },
            error: function (errmsg) {
                alert('error ocured:' + errmsg.responseText);
            },
            success: function (text) {
                alert(text);
            },

        });
    }
```

EDIT
It has to be, 
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: 'json'
and the 405 error disapears.

But now the code ends up in the error callback. I changed the alert function in there to alert('error ocured:' + errmsg.error);
and it gave me this: 
error ocured:

```
function (){
if(!e){
  var c=arguments,g,h,i,j,k;b&&(k=b,b=0);
  for(g=0,h=c.length;
        g<h;g++)i=c[g],j=d.type(i),j==="array"?f.done.apply(f,i):j==="function"&&a.push(i);
        k&&f.resolveWith(k[0],k[1])
 }return this
}
```

In chrome I get the error in the console:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `https://xxx.jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/`. Origin `http://localhost:49592` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Does anybody know what the error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible. The error you got is saying that you can't do cross domain  XMLHttp Request. you can find more information on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098662/still-confused-about-using-xmlhttprequest-cross-domain).

One way to go around it, is to create a local API, using php (or any other language), that will serve the ajax calls made by jQuery.

For example, write a [PHP page](https://bitbucket.org/miknight/atlassian-example-scripts/src/e2f2dea9e8ed/jira_create_issue.php) that will create issues via the [REST API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/), then use the javascript to post to this page all the needed details.

Let me know if you need any help.

**EDIT**

to do it using C#, The easiest way ill probably be using something like [JiraRestClient.NET](https://bitbucket.org/MikeJansen/jirarestclient.net/wiki/Home).

If you prefer to code it yourself, here is some info about [connecting to Jira using REST](http://maffelu.net/jira-basic-cjira-connection-using-rest).

Comment: Do you also know how to do it in c#?

Answer (score 1):

Your content type should be `'application/json'`, not `'application/jsonp'`.

Comment: Yes you were right, it has to be, 
contentType: 'application/json',
and even
dataType: 'json',

But now I get the error callback: error ocured: (without a responseText) ?

Comment: i changed to alert('error ocured:' + errmsg.error); and it gave me this:  function (){if(!e){var c=arguments,g,h,i,j,k;b&&(k=b,b=0);for(g=0,h=c.length;g<h;g++)i=c[g],j=d.type(i),j==="array"?f.done.apply(f,i):j==="function"&&a.push(i);k&&f.resolveWith(k[0],k[1])}return this} does anybody know what the error is?

Comment: That is ... very hard to read. Please amend your question to include the new information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was due to the fact I was using HTTP instead of HTTPS.