# Cross-site xmlhttp requests returning status 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest, cross-site

I have a page which calls an XMLHttpRequest to a page from another site. The problem is, the status returned is 0.
The code of the caller page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML Template</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Dev-PHP 2.6.0" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="your,keywords,here" />
<meta name="Description" content="." />

</head>
<body>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="txtReturn" id="txtReturn" size=75 />
</p>

<textarea name="taStatus" id="taStatus" cols="75" rows="25"></textarea>

<p>&nbsp; </p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getReturn()
{
    var txtBox = document.getElementById("txtReturn");
    var taStatus = document.getElementById("taStatus");

    txtBox.value = "Preparing to get Response";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        // alert('IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari');
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        // alert('IE6, IE5');
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {   
        taStatus.innerHTML = taStatus.innerHTML + "URL: " + url + ".\nReadyStatus: " + xmlhttp.readyState + ".\nStatus: " + xmlhttp.status + ".\nStatusText: " + xmlhttp.statusText + ".\nresponseText: " + xmlhttp.responseText + ".\n\n";

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
                // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            txtBox.value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }

    }

    var url = 'http://www.ip.com.om/site/checkdata.php';
    var url2 = 'http://badihbarakat.com/site/checkdata.php';
    var url3 = '../site/checkdata.php';

    xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
    // url = url + ((/\?/).test(url) ? "&" : "?") + (new Date()).getTime();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}

    getReturn();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The called .php page on the other site, just echo a string with the date and time.

Can anyone advise what can be the problem? I am using FireFox 27 and I have checked the Error Browser and it is showing:

```
**GET http://www.ip.com.om/site/checkdata.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 710ms]**
```

and when you click it, the details of the request shows:

```
Request URL:    http://www.ip.com.om/site/checkdata.php
Request Method:     GET
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 200 OK

**Request Headers 17:27:37.000**
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
Referer:    http://badihbarakat.com/local/
Origin: http://badihbarakat.com
Host:   www.ip.com.om
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

**Response Headers Δ710ms**
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.3.26
X-CFLO-Cache-Result:    TCP_REFRESH_MISS
Server: Apache
Date:   Sat, 01 Mar 2014 13:27:42 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html
Content-Length: 37
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age:    0
```

Awaiting your valuable replies...

Badih Barakat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security issues,you can't do xmlhttp requests to a server in a different domain.
You could either consume the service from server side code and then possible proxy it to the page via your own service.
check the following post.
[Still confused about using XMLHTTPRequest cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098662/still-confused-about-using-xmlhttprequest-cross-domain)

Comment: So this is not even possible to get the outcome of the called page?

Comment: I have tried the code in the referred URL [link](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html) `Making cross domain JavaScript requests using XMLHttpRequest or XDomainRequest`

Comment: It is working now... the missing part was in the called .php file... many thanks for the reference... :)